# LINQ returns An unhandled exception when bounding to dataGridView

Tags: entity-framework, linq

New to LINQ... I have this simple statement on `Form_Load`:

```
ABC_TrackingEntities Empl = new ABC_TrackingEntities();
var abca = from empl in Empl.Employees
           select empl;
dataGridView1.DataSource = abca;
```

When I run this, I get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred
>   in EntityFramework.dll

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

i am not quite sure if DataSource is able to work with Queryables.

The Linq-Statement is returning the result as a `Queryable of Emp.Employees` Try converting the result to a list via adding `ToList()` at abca.

```
ABC_TrackingEntities Empl = new ABC_TrackingEntities();
var abca = from empl in Empl.Employees
           select empl;
dataGridView1.DataSource = abca.ToList();
```

But this is just a guess, may be show the whole Exception Stack Trace.

Comment: @Timax one hint if performance may count in your Case and if you could excpect Millions of rows returned by your statement. AS ToList will transfer everything from your server to your client every row will be touched and that could result in poor performance.

Comment: I will use where statement for this so it's not an issue. Thank you

Comment: Can you please explain me why I am not getting results when I change dataGridView to ListBox? I get no errors but ListBox populates "LINQTest.Empoyee" in every line instead of values... Do I need different approach with ListBox?

Comment: This is because Listbox doesn't know which element to display of your lists objects. So it takes the standard implementation of ToString(). You could override ToString() in you class or you define the Element to display by setting DisplayMemberPath.

Comment: Thank you Dom84! Can you please give me simple example? Was searching internet for the DisplayMemberPath but the only thing I see is how to populate manually but I need to get data from table